# Should NLST FTP command return records with or without absolute paths?

Tags: linux, ftp, relative-path, absolute-path, rfc

in my Java project I am using [Apache FTP Client](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) to download some data from FTP server.

On production there is running some FTP server on Linux which returns files with abosulte paths when using NLST. So my response for NLST `/home` might be e.g. `/home/user`.

For testing I am using [Mock FTP Server](http://mockftpserver.sourceforge.net/) and surprisingly this mock FTP server returns relative paths when using NLST. So for the example above is will return only `user`.

I was wondering (and didn't find out even not in [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html)) if there is some standard if the `NLST` should return absolute or relative paths. Maybe there is some switch for this purpose? Sofar I stick with checking the returned names if they are or are not relative and if they are I make them absolute myself. But maybe there is better solution out there?

Just to note I am using `FakeUnixFileSystem` for testing so OS type should not be involved in this issue.

Comment: Maybe you remember, that Linux and FTP server you used? Now I have same problem (absolute path) from "black box" and I want to find any clues

Comment: I don't, sorry :/ It is 7 years back ...

Answer (score 0):

NLST is supposed to return a list of relative file names with no other information about them whatsoever, so I'd say Mock FTP Server is doing the right thing.